# Changing the chain order of the methods in NumPy is giving None and different output

Tags: python, numpy

I ran the following code related to Numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,4],[3,1]])

np_array = np.sort(a.flatten())
print(np_array)

np_array2 = a.flatten().sort()
print(np_array2)
```

I got the following output.

```
[1 1 3 4]
None
```

I expected this output.

```
[1 1 3 4]
[1 1 3 4]
```

Why is this difference in the output? What concept of programming is this?

Comment: Calling `___.sort()` sorts the array in place. If you did `np_array2 = a.flatten()` then `np_array2.sort()`, then `print(np_array2)`would give you a sorted array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get none because `.sort()` operates differently from `sorted()` or `np.sort()`. The `*.sort()` is in place (ie. the original list) whereas the other methods both create a **new** list.

So this is an example that works (the way you want it):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,4],[3,1]])

np_array = np.sort(a.flatten())
print('nparraay', np_array)

np_array2 = a.flatten()
print('nparraay2 (part 1):', np_array2)

np_array2 = np.sort(np_array2)
print('nparraay2 (part 2):', np_array2)
```

result:

```
nparraay [1 1 3 4]
nparraay2 (part 1): [1 4 3 1]
nparraay2 (part 2): [1 1 3 4]
```